# Training YOLO (object detection) on multiple objects on imbalanced dataset?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo, multiclass-classification

I'm training YOLO on custom dataset(using Alexey AB implementation of Darknet). It has 3 classes of images where class 1 has 45k images, and remaining two have around 1k images.

After training it for 6k iterations, the loss is in between 1.5 and 2. However, when i tried running it on a video, it is only detecting class 1.

I would like to know what is the reason for this, is it because of the imbalance in the no of images in the dataset? Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, to begin with you've an unbalanced dataset. The recommended number of images per class is >2000 (according to the [directions on the repository](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-improve-object-detection)).

I'd recommend you to have a *test set* and track your **mean average precision** along with **loss** while you're training. If the average precision is low, you can assume that not all classes are being detected equally well.

There are a few ways to solve this but I'm assuming you already might have figured out.

- Collect more data for other classes.
- Try data augmentation for other classes with rotation, noise, etc.
- You could try adding synthetic images for the other classes.
- Even though it's a bad idea to leave out data for the 1st class, at least try reducing it so there's a balanced dataset.

I'm calling *other classes* for the classes with less data.

Comment: To add to this, you could also define a custom loss function that weighs an error for a class it has less examples more than one for a class with more examples. You can read more about that [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data#class_weights)